# How can I Project the red polygon on the green rectangle?

Tags: c#, geometry, coordinates, polygon, rectangles

How can I Project the red polygon on the green rectangle?

In fact, I know the coordinates of each corner, but I can't find a result on how to Project it or calculate the no overlapped areas
(the red polygon can change coordinates ).
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rks5O.png)

[image: image2]

Comment: Do vertices of red always lie on green edges?

Comment: no not always . in some cases ,there is no intersection

Comment: @MBo clipping will result in damagin the polygon! The question stated that the polygon's points could be changed to make the polygon fits inside the rectangle, so it is a shape-shift/scale problem, if am not wrong.. Right @AMAL?

Comment: @Muhammad Sulaima Problem is not stated well, so it's hard to say what is really needed.

Comment: yes sir, i just want the coordinates of the red one became like the green one(resizing)

Comment: It is worth to describe your task better

Comment: Please share your code so far.

Comment: This discussion may be useful - [Mapping Irregular Quadrilateral to a Rectangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13404/mapping-irregular-quadrilateral-to-a-rectangle)